# Vectorize a raster TIFF based on its different class colors

Tags: qgis, raster, vectorization

I am using QGIS 3.16 and I have an int ratser tiff file, which shows classified land covers obtained from Sentinel-2. I need to create polygons over each class to classify and visualize each group in a vector format. As shown in the image attached, the areas corresponding to each class are so scattered and there is not just this one image so I cannot draw polygons manually. I thought of using an specific field in the attribute table to separate a class, but it does not have an attribute table! Any ideas on how I can vectorize a raster based on its different class colors?

[image]

The zoomed in result from using polygonize tool under GDAL>raster conversion is like below over the same area. For example, all the light green area which is just one class, shows many many polygons instead of just one big polygon over the light green area

[image]

[image]

The ratser is classified as below:

[image]

I wrote this classification table and I got this result which only has to values of 0 and 13 instead of 1 to 5 that I was expecting:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just polynonize the raster. A separate polygons will be created for all distinct raster values. Value will be written into an attribute.

Comment: Thank you @user30184, I have done that and it gives me results like the image I attach. A you see in this area that there is mostly light green, I was expecting just one polygon line covering all area but the result of GDAL >raster conversion>polygonize is something like the second image that has many many polygons that I do not know why are created as they all are part of just one class.

Comment: You can dissolve your polygons on your class number

Comment: Thanks @MarcM, would you please explain a bit to me how to do that?

Comment: I do not quite understand. If you have several classes on the area, how could a single polygon present it all? You can split the layer that covers the whole area by attribute value into separate layers if you want separate layers for each value. About the last image with lots of polygons, have you checked the values of the classifying attribute? Are they really the same for all the polygons? Could you share some test data?

Comment: You can try dissolving via vector > Geoprocessing tools > Dissolve. Then for 'dissolve fields' select the field indicating your classes.

Comment: Reclassify your raster so for example all your light green areas get the same value then vectorize. As of now I'm guessing your light green values actually have different values but you grouped them together in the styling so for example values from 10-100 are light green

Comment: Thanks @MarcM. I tried dissolve but it fails to compute. As for dissolve fields, there is just one field existing in my data and I select it and it gives an error.

Comment: What is the error message? @BERA, good suggestion, this could very well be the case!

Comment: Thansk @BERA. You are right. There were 6 classes with the same green color. For performing your suggestion, I found the Reclassify by layer and table tools but I guess I cannot use these options because I dont have a layer containg class breaks or classification table. I am better with Arcmap but I am new with QGIS.

Comment: @MarcM The error is: Feature (217) from “polygonize” has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the “Ignore invalid input features” option.
Execution failed after 0.05 seconds

Comment: Within the reclassify table you can define your own class breaks in the classification table

Comment: Thanks @MarcM, I add the pictures of the existing classes in my question. If I add rows to the table, it askes me for minimum and maximum values, however, as shown in this table, values from 0 to 7 plus 11 belong to the same class. How can I reclassify these values ?

Comment: You can try this: use 1 row to classify values from 0 - 7 to "1" then define a separate row to classify 11 - 11 to "1". Same for soil (=suolo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116459/discussion-between-paris-and-marcm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following from the discussion and chat:

First, reclassify your raster data using `Reclassify by table` with range boundary "min <= value <= max".  For each interval use 1 row, according to your classes e.g.;

row 1: (0 - 7) = 1,

row 2: (11 - 11) = 1.

Then polynonize your raster. Finally, symbolize your vector layer using, `Properties > Symbology` and make it "Categorized" using the new class values of 1-5.